# Trying to access LUIS with Azure portal generated subscription key returns 401

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I have created a Preview instance of Cognitive Services LUIS in the Azure portal. I am not using the http://www.luis.ai/test/beta portal.

First off the endpoint that the Azure portal displays seems wrong (empirical testing confirms this):
https://api.projectoxford.ai/luis/v1

The correct endpoint seems to be:

https://api.projectoxford.ai/luis/v1.0

This is confirmed by looking at another CS: Face, which has a listed endpoint of:

https://api.projectoxford.ai/face/v1.0

Using either key 1 or key 2 from the Azure portal and trying the following CURL command:

```
curl -v -X GET "https://api.projectoxford.ai/luis/v1.0/prog/apps"
     -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: <my key>" --data-ASCII "{body}"
```

This, and all other requests to any of the LUIS functions, returns:

> 401. "Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription".

Using the exact same format with a Face CS created from the Azure portal works as expected.

Is this a sign that LUIS has not made it all the way into Azure yet, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: After generating your LUIS key from Azure, did you update your subscription key on your LUIS app? If not, try again after doing that. You can do so from the LUIS dashboard.

Comment: I do not use the LUIS portal itself. I just created the service from the Azure portal and used the test console, CURL and an app to try to talk to it. From what I understand the LUIS portal is just for the test/preview version of LUIS and will stop working on December 31st 2016. The LUIS portal links to Azure to purchase a "real" version of the service.

Comment: I am having this exact same issue. Linking an Azure subscription key to an app created in luis.ai portal didn't help either. I created a support ticket with Microsoft and will let you know if I hear back. The only way I can work with LUIS is via the programmatic key off of luis.ai. Unfortunately, luis.ai login process doesn't support SSO with our enterprise AD like other Microsoft services do (Office365 and Azure, for example) so I have to use my personal account.

Answer (score 1):

I got a word from the Microsoft Cognitive Services support team:

> You are basically using the programmatic APIs which are used for model building and **these APIs are not metered**. By design, **the Azure subscription keys do not work with the programmatic API**. You would need to use the programmatic keys.
>
> Once you publish the application, you will get an endpoint which would have `luis/v2`. When you use this endpoint in your application you would be using the Azure subscription keys. Anytime you see `prog` in the URL, these are **programmatic endpoints and would not work with the Azure subscription keys**.

I can confirm that the subscription key works with the trained endpoint once you assign that key to the app in [luis.ai](https://www.luis.ai/).

---

#### Extra

I asked about SSO with the enterprise accounts like you get on Office365 or Azure Portal. The response:

> As far as your question about SSO is concerned, unfortunately, it still has not been enabled for luis.ai. However, this is something our Product team is working on and you should [have] federated experience soon.

I asked if I there is an option to share the administration of my [luis.ai](https://www.luis.ai/) apps with someone else like I can do, for example, with the administration of my bot registrations on [dev.botframework.com](https://dev.botframework.com/). The response:

> Not that I know of. However, I will get a conformation from the PG on that as well.

Comment: You can add collaborators in the luis.ai portal.  Collaborators can make changes to the luis.ai apps.

Also adding https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kwill/2017/05/17/http-401-access-denied-when-calling-azure-cognitive-services-apis/ for the various 401 Access Denied scenarios in case others find this page in the future.